# When animation finishes, keep the ending image of the animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have an animation that starts out as a plain back ground. when the animation begins, it plays and when it finishes, the screen goes back to the original background. How can i keep the ending image of my animation and set it as my background? Thanks for the help!!

By the way, what i am asking is similar to a childrens book. When the animation finishes, i want the background to stay the same as the very last part of the animation. So it looks like the animation just stops!

Comment: It's worth mentioning how you're animating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `NSArray` for the images is called `imageArray` and your `UIImageView` is called `imageView`, try this:

```
imageView.image = [imageArray lastObject];
imageView.animationImages = imageArray;
imageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

That should loop through the images once, and then once it ends, leave the `UIImageView` on the last image. Hope that Helps!